# Достать строку из строки

Tags: python

Из строки (334(ii)) мне нужно достать строку 334(ii).

Comment: Приведите примеры как эти строки объявлены или вводятся

Comment: '(334(ii))'[1:-1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
s1 = "(334(ii))"
print(s1[1:-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуемся **срезами** строк.

```py
print('(334(ii))'[1:-1])
```

Вывод:

> 334(ii)